# Content not updated

Tags: next.js, strapi

I know this is a stupid question. But please help me. I create a blog using Strapi, but when I change the content in the Strapi admin panel, the content on the site itself is not updated. I read about this on the Internet. There they write to use either revalidate or getServerSideProps. But I don't know how to change this in my code. I tried changing this, but errors immediately appeared in other places.

blog/page.jsx

```js
'use server'

import React from 'react'
import Card from "@/components/Card"
import config from '@/config'
import fetchBlogs from "@/helpers/fetch-blogs"


const Blog = async () => {
  const [ visibilityBlogs, blogs ] = await Promise.all([
    await fetchBlogs('filters[Visibility][$eq]=true'),
    await fetchBlogs('filters[Visibility][$eq]=false')
  ]);

  return (
    <>
        <div className='main'>

            {visibilityBlogs.data.map(visibilityBlog => (
                <Card
                    key={visibilityBlog.attributes.id} 
                    label={visibilityBlog.attributes.Category} 
                    title={visibilityBlog.attributes.Title} 
                    summary={visibilityBlog.attributes.Summary}
                    date={visibilityBlog.attributes.Date}
                    href={`/blog/${visibilityBlog.attributes.Link}`}
                    imgSrc={`${visibilityBlog.attributes.ImageBig.data.attributes.url}`}
                    imgAlt='Избранное' 
                    className="mt-4"
                />
            ))}

            <div className='grid max-md:grid-cols-1 max-xl:grid-cols-2 grid-cols-3 gap-4 mt-4'>


            {blogs.data.map(blog => (
                <Card
                    key={blog.attributes.id} 
                    label={blog.attributes.Category} 
                    title={blog.attributes.Title} 
                    summary={blog.attributes.Summary}
                    date={blog.attributes.Date} 
                    href={`/blog/${blog.attributes.Link}`}
                    imgSrc={`${blog.attributes.ImageAvatar.data.attributes.url}`}
                    imgAlt='Миниатюра' 
                    className=""
                />
            ))}
            </div>
        </div>
    </>
  )

}

export default Blog;
```

blog/[slug]/page.jsx

```js
'use server'

import React from 'react'
import getCategoryColor from '@/helpers/get-category-color';
import Image from 'next/image';
import config from '@/config'
import fetchBlogs from "@/helpers/fetch-blogs"
import MarkdownIt from "markdown-it"
import Link from 'next/link';
import { ArrowLeft } from 'lucide-react';
import { notFound } from "next/navigation";

const BlogDetails = async (props) => {
  
  const blogs = await fetchBlogs(`filters[Link][$eq]=${props.params.slug}`)

  if (!blogs || blogs.data === null || blogs.data.length === 0) {
    notFound();
  }

  const blog = blogs.data[0];

  // console.log('blogs', blogs.data[0]);

  const md = MarkdownIt({
    html: true
  });
  const result = md.render(blog.attributes.Content);

  return (
    <>
        <div className='main mt-6'>
          <div className='grid grid-cols-[1fr_160px] mb-6 gap-10 items-center'>
            <h2 className='text-4xl'>{blog.attributes.Title}</h2>
            <div id='cardLabel' className={`text-[18px] ${getCategoryColor(blog.attributes.Category)} font-medium justify-center rounded-full flex items-center h-10 justify-self-end min-w-[140px]`}>{blog.attributes.Category}</div>
          </div>

          <div className='flex relative'>
            <Image className='rounded-2xl mb-6' src={`${blog.attributes.ImageBig.data.attributes.url}`} alt="" width={1280} height={387} />
            <div className={`absolute mt-4 ml-4 ${getCategoryColor(blog.attributes.Category)} p-2 flex justify-center items-center rounded-xl backdrop-blur-sm`}>{blog.attributes.Date}</div>
          </div>

          <div className='flex w-full justify-center'>
            <div className='w-9/12 text-justify' dangerouslySetInnerHTML={{__html: result}}></div>
          </div>

          <Link className='back-to-blog rounded-full bg-red-500 hover:bg-red-500/75 s-10 p-3' href="/blog">
              <ArrowLeft />
          </Link>

        </div>
    </>
  )
}

export default BlogDetails;
```

fetch-blogs.js

```js
import config from '@/config'

const fetchBlogs = async (params) => {
    const reqOptions = {
        headers: {
            Authorization: `Bearer ${process.env.API_TOKEN}`
        }
    };

    const request = await fetch(`${config.api}/api/blogs?populate=*&${params}`, reqOptions)
    const response = await request.json();

    return response;
    
}

export default fetchBlogs;
```

Comment: Are you using App router ? This API `/api/blogs?populate=....` is in api folder ?

Comment: @Beast80K No. The config.api file contains the address of the application Strapi. And this is a link to the Strapi API to get post data from there

Comment: When you make a build, do you see this `blog` page as static rendered in terminal ?

Comment: Collecting page data ...
   Generating static pages (0/10) ... /

   Generating static pages (2/10)  /

   Generating static pages (4/10)  /

   Generating static pages (7/10)  /

 ✓ Generating static pages (10/10)  /
   Finalizing page optimization ...
   Collecting build traces ...
Route (app)
 / , /_not-found, /[...not_found], /api/auth/[...nextauth], /blog, /blog/[slug], /dashboard, /dashboard/admin-blog,  /dashboard/admin-works, /signin

Answer (score 0, accepted):

By default, all the `fetch` requests made in next.js are cached. you can edit your `fetch-blogs.js` component like below to opt out of caching which will always show latest content on your strapi backend.

`fetch-blogs.js`

```
import config from "@/config";

const fetchBlogs = async (params) => {
  const request = await fetch(`${config.api}/api/blogs?populate=*&${params}`, {
    headers: { Authorization: `Bearer ${process.env.API_TOKEN}` },
    cache: "no-store",
  });
  const response = await request.json();
  return response;
};

export default fetchBlogs;
```

You can read more about caching in Next.Js [here](https://nextjs.org/docs/app/building-your-application/caching#data-cache)

Comment: Thank you very much. That helped. Now a question has arisen. Is it possible to somehow make the data update without refreshing the page. And do I understand correctly what this does through axios or is it something completely different?

Comment: Sorry, not Axios, but AJAX

Comment: You can use On-demand Revalidation by Next.Js or SWR to revalidate/mutate the data.
I have not used revalidate but you can read about it in the docs. You can however use SWR to fetch your data and calling the mutate() function provided by the useSWR hook from the library which will fetch the data again and update it.

https://nextjs.org/docs/app/building-your-application/data-fetching/fetching-caching-and-revalidating#on-demand-revalidation

https://swr.vercel.app/